# MongoError: Chunks out of Order

Tags: mongodb

I am uploading a file into MongoDB Gridfs with Node.js module mongodb@1.4.9 version.

I get the following error and the server stops.

```
{ [MongoError: exception: chunks out of order]
  name: 'MongoError',
  errmsg: 'exception: chunks out of order',
  code: 10040,
  ok: 0
}
```

It has become a blocker for me. Is there a solution for error code 10040.
I am using 64-bit mongodb on ubuntu 12.04 and above

Comment: What version of MongoDB, and is this a sharded cluster?

Comment: upgrading the version to 2.6.4 resolved it